# How to get both month and year together from a date in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a column in report that should display month and year together i.e single column will have both month and year(this is the first column of the table).

Ex: JAN/11

```
  FEB/11

    .

    .

 DEC/11
```

How can I do this?

Regards,

N.SRIRAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume datecolumn will be your column name and here goes the query -

```
select DATENAME(month, datecolumn) + '/' + Right(Year(datecolumn),2) from myTable
```

if you want to show only first three chars always, then -

```
select CAST(DATENAME(month,datecolumn) as nvarchar(3)) + '/' + Right(Year(datecolumn),2)
from mytable
```